# Nullable Form Data Is Returning Value "0" In Database

Tags: php, html, laravel, database, null

I'm trying to store an empty input field into my database and would like for it to be stored as "NULL", however, If I leave the input field empty when I go to submit my form, It is stored as "0" in my database.

In my controller, I have the following:

```
$campaignRules = [
            'lines_available' => 'nullable|numeric',
        ];
```

In my form I have:

```
<div class="col-xl-12 input-container">
    <label for="" class="f-14 text-grey label">
        Lines Available (optional)
    </label>
    <input name="lines_available" type="number" class="custom-form" placeholder="Enter lines available...">
</div>
```

In my database, I have the field stored as an integer, have "Allow Nullable" checked and have the default value of the field set as "NULL". I can't think of any other reason as to why it would be stored as 0 with all the things I have set in place.

Any guidance? Thanks again.

Comment: So you're basically asking us, why your validation function makes 0 instead of null out of empty string?

Comment: This validation logic looks like Laravel's Validation. If you're using a Framework, make sure to tag it so we can better focus on your specific issue.

Comment: Yeah I don't get why the value would be stored as 0, rather than being stored as null.

Comment: Because your code makes it 0, not null?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Laravel shouldn't convert `null` to `0` before storing in the database, there's possibly something else happening here. @NathanBayne, You'll have to look at a couple things; the data type of the `lines_available` column, whether or not it allows `null`, (which you have checked, good) etc., and also [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72290560/edit) to include the code that actually performs the insert/update. You're showing the form input and validation, but that's only 2 pieces of the puzzle.

Comment: @TimLewis I have the data type set as an integer and it is set to allow null because I have the "Allow Null" column checked. I thought I'd ask in here just incase it was something obvious that I was maybe doing wrong. I can't pull on code on here. I'll look deeper into it.

Comment: Yeah, I saw you included that after that fact; that all looks correct. I haven't personally seen this happen before, but without seeing your `Model::create()`, `Model::insert()`, `$model = new Model(); ... $model->save();`, and/or the actual Model (might be casting or something else in there), there's not much help we can provide. Hope you figure it out!

Comment: Yeah you're all good. I'm sure it'll be something minor. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @TimLewis where you all get that null from? I fail to see any code that could possibly return null. How Laravel is responsible for converting null into 0 when there was not a single null value in the input?

Comment: @YourCommonSense Sorry, what are you asking? I'm saying that Laravel _shouldn't_ convert `null` to `0` when saving the `lines_available` column. The OP didn't (and can't/will not) include the actual code that is doing the saving, so I can't confirm anything. Also, `null` would be sent if nothing was filled in the form input for `lines_available`. It's a `number` type field, but that can still be empty (which will send `''`, edit: not `null`, to the backend, not `0`).

Comment: @TimLewis since when HTTP allows to transport anything other than strings? How it's possible for the HTML form to send null to backend?

Comment: @YourCommonSense It doesn't   But, Laravel does things with the request input behind the scenes to convert `''` to `null` if the `nullable` validation rule is included (and in other instances). Have you worked with Laravel at all before?

Comment: @TimLewis not much. Does it *really* convert an empty string into null? No wonder it is so much despised.

Comment: @YourCommonSense Lol, is _that_ what makes Laravel despised?? And yes, yes it does. Given the form field `<input type="text" name="label"/>`, if I don't fill it in, `$request->input('label')` is `null`, not `''`. `$_POST['label']` by comparison is `''`, not `null`. 

Comment: @TimLewis not only that of course. Just another example. Thanks for the info

Comment: @YourCommonSense Haha no worries, I was being slightly sarcastic; I know people don't love PHP and/or Laravel for _many_ reasons, a lot of which are very valid. As a PHP dev, I hear it all the time. And no problem for the info!

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by doing the following:

```
if ($_REQUEST['lines_available'] == 0) {
    $campaign->lines_available = null;
}
```

This is done before the entry is saved within the controller.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why are you using `$_REQUEST` instead of the `$request` or `request()` object? Typically, you access the input via `$request->get('lines_available')` (or `request()->input('lines_available')`, etc.)